# weak delegate becomes nil before the delegation event method called

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I have some heavy processing tasks in my view controller, so I put them in a background thread using GCD. And the tasks are encapsulated in a class AsyncImageProcessor

```
@interface AsyncProcessor : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<AsyncProcessorDelegate> delegate;

// ... other unrelated stuff

@end

@protocol AsyncProcessorDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) asyncProcessorEvent:(AsyncProcessorEventType) event;

@end
```

The problem is that the view controller implementing the delegate is dismissed right after the AsyncProsessor tasks dispatched. And by the time the processing is done, the view controller memory is released, delegate is nil. Then delegated event can't be passed back to the view controller.

One solution I can think of is to define the delegate "strong", and in the delegated method asyncProcessorEvent, set delegate to nil to break the memory circle after all the processing is done. But I feel this is a hack, and I was told everywhere the delegate should be defined as "weak".

Has someone had this issue before? Please give some suggestions.

Comment: If the delegate is `nil`, then it shouldn't matter that the event doesn't get delivered because there is no one interested in it anymore.  If the view controller is the ultimate consumer of the information, why isn't it the delegate?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, your argument is valid. The ultimate consumer is the presenting view controller of the presenting view controller, it's too far away from the AsyncProcessor. Maybe I should use NSNotification in this case.

Comment: Notifications do seem like the best solution for your use case.